# jQuery script to validate number on entering

Tags: jquery, numeric

I would like to know if there's possible to perform the following task with jQuery: prevent the user from entering a number greater than 10 or less than 0.

For example, a number like 9.10 is ok, but 81, 10.01, 11, or a negative number are wrong values.

For a better understanding of the situation, the validation is for entering grades after a test.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure it's possible.  What have you tried?  When do you want the check to happen?  On blur?  On submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will only allow you to enter numbers in the box and will not accept any input that would make the number smaller than 0 and greater than 10.

```
var $grade = $('#grade');

$grade.keydown( function (e) {
    var code = e.which,
        chr = String.fromCharCode(code), // key pressed converted to s string
        cur = $grade.val(),
        newVal = parseFloat(cur + chr); // what the input box will contain after this key press

    // Only allow numbers, periods, backspace, tabs and the enter key
    if (code !== 190 && code !== 8 && code !== 9 && code !== 13  && !/[0-9]/.test(chr)) {
        return false;
    }

    // If this keypress would make the number
    // out of bounds, ignore it
    if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 10) {
        return false;
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WPdVq/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display something as they exit the input field, you could use the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$('.target').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() > 10) {
        // Do something, like warn them and/or reset to empty text.
        alert('Greater than 10.');
        $(this).val('');
    }       
});
```

[jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/absynce/bRxJT/)

Alternatively, if you wanted to display something after each keystroke, you could use the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event.

Comment: Looks nice, thanks. Can it be updated so it will only accept numeric values and dot?

Comment: Check out the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10096685/448876) by Useless Code.  He has a more complete answer including your request.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this library:
[jquery-numeric](https://github.com/byllc/jquery-numeric)

The homepage of the plug-in is here:
http://code.webmonkey.uk.com/plugins/

There is a demo and use can viewsource to see the use of it:

http://code.webmonkey.uk.com/plugins/jquery.numeric/test.html